# Somar valor total de cada categoria LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho uma Lista de compras(ShoppingItens) assim:

```
Descricao: Padaria Campobelo
Valor: -24.00
Data: 06-03-2019
Categoria: Alimentacao

Descricao: Uber tecnologia
Valor: -24.00
Data: 07-03-2019
Categoria: Transporte

Descricao: Uber tecnologia
Valor: -30.00
Data: 08-03-2019
Categoria: Transporte
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar a categoria com o maior gasto, tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
var result = (from item in ListShoppingItens
              group item by item.Categoria into cat
              select new ShoppingItens
              {
                  Valor = cat.Sum(x => x.Valor)
             }).ToList();
```

Porém ele esta retornando apenas uma categoria, no caso a de viagens

A minha classe está assim:

```
public class ShoppingItens
{
    public enum Category 
    {
        VIAGEM,
        DIVERSAO,
        ALIMENTACAO,
        HOSPEDAGEM,
        VESTUARIO,
        TRANSPORTE,
        HIGIENE,
        SEMCATEGORIA,
    }

    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public Category Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: porque o valor é negativo? qual é mesmo o output que pretende (com exemplo)? porque na lista que deu de amostra colocou uma categoria  que não existe (supermercado)?

Comment: O valor é negativo porque é o valor que ele gastou naquela compra específica, ou seja, o dinheiro que saiu, se houver um valor positivo quer dizer que ele recebeu o dinheiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo em Console Application pra mostrar como pegar o valor agrupado de cada categoria.

```
var ListShoppingItens = new List<ShoppingItens>
        {
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.ALIMENTACAO, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 1770 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.DIVERSAO, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 1640 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.SEMCATEGORIA, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 410 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.ALIMENTACAO, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 150 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.TRANSPORTE, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 160 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.ALIMENTACAO, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 106 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.HIGIENE, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 160 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.HIGIENE, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 1044 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.ALIMENTACAO, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 1440 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.TRANSPORTE, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 150 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.ALIMENTACAO, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 1550 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.DIVERSAO, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 10 },
            new ShoppingItens { Data = DateTime.Now, Categoria = ShoppingItens.Category.ALIMENTACAO, Descricao = "TESTE", Valor = 12220 }
        };


        var resultado = from item in ListShoppingItens
                     group item by item.Categoria into cat
                     select new 
                     {
                         Categoria = cat.Key,
                         Total = cat.Sum(x => x.Valor),
                     };


        foreach (var item in resultado)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Categoria + "-" + item.Total);
```

Comment: Funcionou, estava quase lá rs. Só um detalhe no seu código, a classe ShoppingItens não possui a propriedade Total, então precisei criá-la, mas mesmo assim obrigado.

Comment: No meu código a propriedade Total é anônima, por isso não foi necessário cria-la. 
Fico contente que tenha funcionado. Bons códigos :)